# csv with header (H) and related record (R) rows: how to scan R rows and input a value into the related H row

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

I am hoping someone can help me out. I have searched extensively and can't find a solution.

I am unfortunately not knowledgeable about advanced programming within Excel and therefore if anyone has any thoughts or insights, please be as detailed as possible. Thank you in advance!

I have a large spreadsheet that has thousands of rows of data. There are many related groups within the spreadsheet, and each group has a single H row (header) and a bunch of associated R rows (records). The number of R rows will vary. The spreadsheet distinguishes between the two by placing either a "H" or a "R" in each cell in column A.

The H and R rows are linked by the fact that they have an exact (and unique to the sheet)match in column B.

Here is what I'm trying to do. I'd like to look at column J of each R row. If a column J cell says the word "INCONSISTENT" in any of the R rows that are linked to an H row, then I would like column L of the associated H row to say "INCONSISTENT".

But if the word "INCONSISTENT" does not exist in any column J cell in the R rows, then I want column L of the associated H row to say "CONSISTENT".

Hope this all makes sense.

To summarize, I want to find a way so that each H row will have either "CONSISTENT" or "INCONSISTENT" in the cell in column L. This tagging in column L of the H row will depend entirely on whether the word "INCONSISTENT" shows up in any of the associated R rows.

I have literally about 20,000 H rows to populate if possible. So I would like to find a way to program this in but have no clue how to do so.

I tried to attach an image of csv, but not sure if that worked. If someone wants, I can email a copy of it.

Data sample:

[image: Sample]

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Provide a link to your image here - someone with enough rep will ad it to your post

Comment: Thank you Peter. Here is a link to an example of the data. It is a jpg at the bottom of this webpage.  http://rxtox.com/lab_results.aspx

Comment: Thanks for posting the picture of the sample data. Based on this picture and my description above, I would like to find a way to program this spreadsheet so that the following info is input into the H rows: L1 = CONSISTENT, L9 = INCONSISTENT, L14 = INCONSISTENT. Please let me know if I can clarify anything.

Comment: Could you please provide csv / excel the same way? that would dramatically speed up the solution.

Comment: Just in case - at least visible part from the screen will be fine

Comment: Hi again. On that same page (rxtox.com/lab_results.aspx), there is now a hyperlink at the bottom of the page that has the file in a spreadsheet link. Can't say it enough - thanks for your time and effort!

Comment: Please try the solution I already submitted as an answer - it seems working for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this formula typed in `L1` and autofilled down as required will do the job:

`=IF($A1="H",IF(SUMPRODUCT(--($B1=$B:$B),--($J:$J="INCONSISTENT")),"INCONSISTENT","CONSISTENT"),"")`

Sample file (with only relevant data columns): https://www.dropbox.com/s/a89u994zbi5hoki/HRConsistency.xlsx

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you very much for your help Peter!